# How do I parse a JSON to JTree and vice versa

Tags: java, json, jtree

I'm using Java, and I want to parse a complex JSON String (one that contains objects, arrays with values, and arrays of objects to a JTree) and vice versa. 
I was able to create a method that parses the JSON string (using Jackson `ObjectMapper` and `JsonNode`) to a JTree, but now I want the tree to be editable.  And once changed, I want to be able to parse it back to a JSON String or to my Java class represented by the JSON String.  Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can advice you to use `GSON`(https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to convert your data to complex JTree structure and vice versa.
So you can grab your `Java class represented by the JSON String` from your tree and convert it to JSON easily with `GSON`.

As example:

```
ComplexTreeObject obj = new ComplexTreeObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Comment: The sites.google.com link is requiring an account in order to view it.  This is a common Sites configuration problem where not all of the pages are set to public.